# In SAS, How do you find whitespace in a macro variable?

Tags: sas

How do you find the position of whitespace in a macro variable? For example,

```
%let someString = the quick brown fox;
%let nextSpace = %index(&someString,' ');
```

The above code doesn't work. `&nextSpace` will be equal to 0. However, I suspect there should be a way to find the position of a space in a macro variable.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
%let nextSpace = %index(&someString,%str( ));
```

Quotes don't work in macro variables, of course.  You need to use macro quoting, such as `%str` in this case.